# Игра на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Суть игры: произвольная фигура (circle, square, triangle, rhombus) движется слево направо в игровом поле 80% от ширины браузера. Когда игрок нажимает на фигуру она исчезает, очки добавляются к счету (от 0 до 100 очков, в зависимости от того, насколько далеко фигура успела сместится от левого края). Следующая произвольная фигура начинает движение. Пока получилось так (неправильно и совсем по-дилетантски):

```js
$("#circle").animate({ left: '100%' }, 7000 );

$("#rhombus").hide();

$("#circle").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $("#rhombus").show().animate({ left: '100%' }, 7000 );
  $('#count').html(+$('#count').html()+1);
});
```

```css
    body {
      text-align: center; 
      background: #F0EFEE;
      color: #777;
    }

    #count {
      position: fixed;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      background: #fff;
      font: 1.5rem/1 monospace;
      border-radius: .25rem;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
      z-index:20;
      left:20px;
      top:15px;
    }

    .linear { 
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative; 
      margin: 20px 16px 20px 20px; 
      width: 80%; 
      height: 400px; 
      background:white; 
    }

    #left {
      background: #F0EFEE;
      width: 10%;
      height: 100%; 
      top:0;
      left:0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index:15;
    }

    #right {
      background: #F0EFEE;
      width: 11%;
      height: 100%; 
      top:0;
      left:89%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index:15;
    }

    #circle {
      position: absolute;
      width: 45px;
      height: 45px;
      left: 0;
      top: 150px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #F6AC31;

    }

    #rhombus {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: transparent transparent #00BFFF transparent;
        border-width: 0 15px 15px 15px;
        height: 0;
        width: 30px;
        left: 0;
        top: 150px;
        position: absolute;

    }
    #rhombus:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: -15px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #00BFFF transparent transparent transparent;
        border-width: 40px 30px 0 30px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="count">0</div>
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>

  <div class="linear">
   <i id="circle"></i>
   <i id="rhombus"></i>
 </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gc0jv3s8/1/

Comment: А вопрос какой ? :D

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk вопрос в том, что клик действует только на первую картинку (естественно), и как с этим бороться

Comment: вопрос в том, как это заставить работать. т.е. отдельные моменты понимаю (например, чтобы рандомно выбирать фигуры используем Math.random() ), а вот как собрать всё - сложно для понимания пока что

Comment: если уж так делать - лучше создавать элементы на лету и вешать на них click. но лучше посмотрите на что нибудь типа pixii

Comment: @zb' без использования сторонних движков

Comment: А в чем смысл их не использовать? Вот я вижу у вас jquery, чем другие хуже?

Comment: @zb' ничем не хуже, условия задачи такие

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно стоит разбивать логику на вспомогательные и оборачивать это в функции (методы) для выделения общей логики по работе с элементами с одинаковым поведением..

Например вот несколько оберток в виде функций:

- `getRandomInt` - дает рандомный выбор элементов из массива. На данный момент он состоит из двух: `['circle', 'rhombus'];`. Но можешь добавлять неограниченное их количество (в соответствии с их существованием, конечно).
- `init` - для любой начальной инициализации. На данный момент там прячутся все фигуры, чтобы не было видно. Хотя это можно сделать в *CSS*, но данная функция призвана показать, что возможны и должны быть сделаны какие-либо действия до основной игры.
- `spawn` - собственно делает порождение элементов:

  1. берет рандомный индекс из массива элементов
  2. определяет его идентификатор. Так как мы знаем его индекс в массиве, то его идентификатор будет равен `#` плюс имя, которое мы достали из массива по индексу.
  3. запускает саму анимацию
  4. навешивает слушателя клика на элемент с данным идентификатором. **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** - прикрепляет событие к элементу. Причем прикрепляет это к динамически созданному элементу. Хотя в данном случае это не обязательно....Хотя....Обязательно!))
  5. При клике на выбранный элемент

     - открепляем событие клика (**[off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**). Зачем нам плодить событие?
     - останавливаем анимацию (**[stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)**)
     - возвращаем элемент в начальную позицию
     - прячем
     - заново запускаем генерацию `spawn`

---

Пример кода смотрим ниже:

```js
var elements = ['circle', 'rhombus'];

function init() {
  $('.linear > i').hide();
}

function spawn() {
    var elNum = getRandomInt(0, elements.length);
    var elId = "#"+(elements[elNum]);    
    $(elId).show().animate({ left: '100%' }, 7000 );    
    
    $(document).on('click', elId, function(){      
        $(document).off('click', elId);        
        $(this).stop( true, true ).css('left', 0).hide();              
        $('#count').html(+$('#count').html()+1);
        spawn();        
    });
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}


init();
spawn();
```

```css
body {
      text-align: center; 
      background: #F0EFEE;
      color: #777;
    }

    #count {
      position: fixed;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      background: #fff;
      font: 1.5rem/1 monospace;
      border-radius: .25rem;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
      z-index:20;
      left:20px;
      top:15px;
    }

    .linear { 
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative; 
      margin: 20px 16px 20px 20px; 
      width: 80%; 
      height: 400px; 
      background:white; 
    }

    #left {
      background: #F0EFEE;
      width: 10%;
      height: 100%; 
      top:0;
      left:0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index:15;
    }

    #right {
      background: #F0EFEE;
      width: 11%;
      height: 100%; 
      top:0;
      left:89%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index:15;
    }

    #circle {
      position: absolute;
      width: 45px;
      height: 45px;
      left: 0;
      top: 150px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #F6AC31;

    }

    #rhombus {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: transparent transparent #00BFFF transparent;
        border-width: 0 15px 15px 15px;
        height: 0;
        width: 30px;
        left: 0;
        top: 150px;
        position: absolute;

    }
    #rhombus:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: -15px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #00BFFF transparent transparent transparent;
        border-width: 40px 30px 0 30px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="count">0</div>
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>

  <div class="linear">
   <i id="circle"></i>
   <i id="rhombus"></i>
 </div>
</body>
```

---

На самом деле дорабатывать и улучшать тут можно еще много. Но как черновик для начала - достаточно.

Вообще хочу напомнить, что для анимации (особенно для игры) скорее лучше использовать  **[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)**, а то и вовсе **[requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame)**. И скорее не элементы DOM дерева, а canvas и WebGL.

Comment: спасибо большое! особенно за комментарии. на начальном этапе освоения js очень ментора не хватает.